# Неверное отображение текстовой информации в функции

Tags: c++, list

Функция print некорректно выводит имя учащегося. Я знаю, что для работы со списками существует отдельная библиотека, но суть задания в том, чтобы добиться результата без неё. А так же не выводит всех данных из списка. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    int age;
    string name;    
};
struct Node
{
    Data d;
    Node* link;
};

void print(Node* first)
{
    Node* next = first; 
    cout << "Список: \n";
    while (next) {
        string as;
        cout << "Имя: " << next->d.name << ";\n";
        cout << "Возраст: " << next->d.age << ";\n";
        next = next->link;
    }
}




void add(Node* first)
{
    int a;
    string b;
    Node* next;                         //Создаём новый контейнер для нашего списка
    next = first;                       //В данный момент соответствующий начальному контейнеру списка

    next->link = new Node;              //Создаём место в памяти для нового контейнера
    next = next->link;                  //И передвигаем туда указатель "next"

    cout << "Введите имя учащегося: ";  //Вводим данные в сформированные ячейки
    cin >> b;
    next->d.name = b;

    cout << "Введите возраст учащегося: ";
    cin >> a;
    next->d.age = a;

    next->link = NULL;
}
int main()
{
    int ag;
    string nm;


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");       //1. Укажем, что первый узел пока пуст
    Node* first = NULL;
    
    first = new Node;                   //2. Занимаем место под новый контейнер списка


    cout << "Введите имя учащегося: ";  //3. Вводим данные в список
    cin >> nm;
    first->d.name = nm;

    cout << "Введите возраст учащегося: ";
    cin >> ag;
    first->d.age = ag;

    first->link = NULL;                 //4. Указываем, что следующий элемент списка пока отсутствует
    
    int ad = NULL;                      //5. Добавляем новые элементы, либо отображаем список, если добавление больше не нужно
    cout << "Хотите ли вы добавить новые элементы? (1/0)\n";
    cin >> ad;
    do
    {
            add(first);
            cout << "Продолжить заполнение списка? (1/0)\n";
            cin >> ad;
    } while (ad != 0);
    
    print(first);
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот вывод программы.

Comment: а может проблема все таки в кодировке? попробуйте английские буквы и убрать setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `setlocale` использовать две функции:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251); //Кодировка ввода
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); //Кодировка вывода
```

А насчет того, что вывод не правильный, так вы каждую итерацию присваиваете `first->link` новый созданный элемент, при этом предыдущий введенный затирается. Правильней будет примерно так:

```
Node* temp = first;
do
{
    add(temp);
    temp = temp->link;
    cout << "Продолжить заполнение списка? (1/0)\n";
    cin >> ad;
} while (ad != 0);
```

То есть мы добавляем в `temp->link` новый элемент, а потом строчкой `temp = temp->link` переходим на новый элемент и т.д. То есть по факту `temp` указатель на последний добавленный элемент.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Всё заработало как следует. Сейчас буду разбираться с этим затиранием. Ещё раз большое спасибо вам.\